# "Embedding Google DocList in a Google Site" Script failing

Tags: google-apps-script

The following script was recommended to use a List Page to show a Google Docs folder on a page in a google site.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/embedding_docslist_in_sites#section2

When I try to run it on a recently created folder in Google Drive, the script never seems to finish.

The script still works for a folder created before the switch to google drive, which has a much longer ID.

What am I missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script gallery (open a spreadsheet, click on menu Tools>Script Gallery), search for "Embed Google Docs Folders in a Google Site".

This is an updated version of the script available in the Apps Script documentation. It should work better.

Comment: Hi Romain, thanks for the new version.  It works well, but I've spotted one minor problem.  It doesn't display the first document in the folder specified. When I created a dummy file called "1" in the folder, the missing file appeared - it started with B, so it was at the top of the list.  Any idea what might be causing that?